# Multidimensional List Binding to Listbox

Tags: c#, list, data-binding, listbox, multidimensional-array

I know how to bind a list to a listbox but I created a multidimensional list with the below code but cannot figure out how to bind it to a listbox.

```
public class MultiDimDictList<K, T> : Dictionary<K, List<T>>
    {
        public void Add(K key, T addObject)
        {
            if (!ContainsKey(key)) Add(key, new List<T>());
            base[key].Add(addObject);
        }
    }
```

And then the below to utilize this class and add 2 strings to the list:

```
var myDicList = new MultiDimDictList<string, string>();
        myDicList.Add("Title", "Data");
        myDicList.Add("Title2", "Data2");
```

Basically what I am trying to do is bind this data to a listbox showing only the title's but then when a button is clicked it uses the data portion to complete the process.

I am not sure where to go with this as I have been looking at other posts but haven't found anything similar to what I am trying to do.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Dictionary<K,V>` is not a list. The titles in your case are the keys of the dictionary and those are not sorted. You can access them through the `Keys` property but would have to sort them before binding. Add this property to your `MultiDimDictList`

```
public List<string> Titles { get { return Keys.OrderBy(k => k).ToList(); } }
```

and bind the listbox to this property.

The example above assumes that the keys are of string type. When using the generic type parameter `K` you have to convert to string first (unless you want a list of `K` of cause):

```
public List<string> Titles {
    get {
        return Keys
            .Select(k => k.ToString())
            .OrderBy(s => s)
            .ToList(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: It errors with: cannot implicitly convert list<K> to list<string>  What am I missing?

Comment: Added an example taking account of the generic type parameter.